# Android actions during animation listener

Tags: android, animation, listener

I have an image I can drag on the screen thanks to an OnTouchListener.
While moving this image I draw a thin line that "binds" it to its original position.

Now when I release/drop the image, I have a TranslateAnimation which makes the image go back to its position or out of the screen, depending on the dropping area.

How could I redraw the line during the TranslateAnimation so that the image is still bound to its original position while moving?

In AnimationListener there's onAnimationStart, onAnimationRepeat and onAnimationStop, but I see no trace of a onAnimationProgress or so.

Is there a way to get the changing position of a view while animating? Other than an infinite loop on the view position and an if to check if its position changed...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve what you want by creating your own [Interpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) for the animation and then whatever you want when [getInterpolation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html#getInterpolation%28float%29) is called.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your answer but I'm not currently able to try what you propose. Will get back to this question as soon as time allows me to.